# What is a robust installation process for Nokogiri (on Ubuntu)?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, nokogiri, ubuntu-12.04

I tried to install Nokogiri on my Ubuntu 12.04 system, and got an error that said "`libxslt is missing`", but the `libxslt-dev` and `libxml2-dev` are installed.

Is there a robust installation process?  How can I check the links to dependent libraries?

I used RVM, and the RVM pkg is installed too.

```
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/victor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... yes
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in -lxslt... no
-----
libxslt is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/victor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-iconv-dir
    --without-iconv-dir
    --with-iconv-include
    --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
    --with-iconv-lib
    --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-xslt-dir
    --without-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libxslt-config
    --without-libxslt-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-libxml-2.0-config
    --without-libxml-2.0-config
    --with-libiconv-config
    --without-libiconv-config
    --with-xml2lib
    --without-xml2lib
    --with-xsltlib
    --without-xsltlib


Gem files will remain installed in /home/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@dradis/gems/nokogiri-1.5.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@dradis/gems/nokogiri-1.5.4/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
    enter code here
```

Comment: If the `libxslt` libs are installed, you probably have to specify the path.

Comment: try installing `libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev`?

Comment: Brandon Kreisel these libs are installed.

Comment: Please email the nokogiri-talk mailing list with the contents of your mkmf.log file from the failed install.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have also experienced the same problem with rvm, even though I had done the following, as per documentation:

- `sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev`
- `rvm pkg libxml2` and `rvm pkg libxslt`

The only way I could get this solved was, after a lengthy investigation:

- Uninstall the ruby installation: `rvm remove 1.9.3`
- Delete all `libxslt*` and `libxml2*` libs from `~/.rvm/usr/lib` if you had previously done `rvm pkg ...`
- Reinstall ruby: `rvm install 1.9.3`

Reinstalling *after* the `apt-get` commands seems to be the only way of getting this to work.  Also, ensuring the libs installed with `rvm pkg` don’t interfere helped.

**When everything else fails...**

If everything else fails and you absolutely need the gem installed, you can also rebuild `nokogiri` by applying a simple patch — provided that you have all build tools installed, and with the caveat that this will install the latest and potentially unstable code:

- `git clone git://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri`
- get patch [from this gist](https://gist.github.com/3800001) and save it as `x86_64.patch` in the `nokogiri` folder.
- Apply patch: `patch -p1 < x86_64.patch`
- Rebuild: `rake native gem` — this should build the gem in the `pkg/` folder
- Install the gem using `gem install pkg/nokogiri-<version>-x86_64-linux.gem`

Comment: This actually helped me to resolve an error installing chef via gem on Ubuntu 12.04 using only packages -- I didn't want to use RVM as only 1.9.3 is needed system wide on this box.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to ruby, but this...

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.2' -- --with-xml2-lib=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --with-xml2-include=/usr/include/libxml2 --with-xslt-lib=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --with-xslt-include=/usr/include/libxslt
```

...worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04. (Or, anyway, it satisfied the nokogiri dependency and got me one step closer to what I'm really trying to accomplish.) I thought it might have messed up my RVM magic, but nokogirl-1.5.2 is definitely sitting there in ~/.rvm/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems, so...maybe it's all good?

Comment: generally with non-specific questions like this, it helps the asker (and future searchers) to provide robust solutions that are agnostic to the system / setup, or to instruct about how to analyze and fix a specific part of the process that can cause errors (library linkage, for instance)

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue on Ubuntu 13.04.

I had tried everything that you find all over the place online. Making sure packages listed on the Nokogiri install page are present, etc etc.

The only thing that eventually did it for me was installing libsxlt from source. After that everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use gem install nokogiri -- --with-iconv-dir=/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev ruby1.8 ri1.8 rdoc1.8 irb1.8
sudo apt-get install libreadline-ruby1.8 libruby1.8 libopenssl-ruby
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
```

?