# Can't install ruby gem xmlparser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install this gem `xmlparser` so that I can use the class XSD::QName to read from XML.

It asked me to install `expat` and `xmlparse`, and then after several other packages and attempts I have this new problem:

[image]

"Failed to build gem native extension

Checking for ntohl() in -lsocket... no

etc etc

etc etc

make failed, exit code 2"

**@edit**

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.1 extconf.rb
checking for expat.h... yes
checking for XML_ParserCreate() in -lexpat... yes
checking for XML_SetNotStandaloneHandler()... yes
checking for XML_SetParamEntityParsing()... yes
checking for XML_SetDoctypeDeclHandler()... yes
checking for XML_ParserReset()... yes
checking for XML_SetSkippedEntityHandler()... yes
checking for XML_GetFeatureList()... yes
checking for XML_UseForeignDTD()... yes
checking for XML_GetIdAttributeIndex()... yes
checking for ntohl() in -lsocket... no
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling xmlparser.c
xmlparser.c: In function ‘XMLParser_parse’:
xmlparser.c:1783:2: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
  rb_raise(eXMLParserError, (char*)errStr);
  ^
xmlparser.c:1832:5: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
     rb_raise(eXMLParserError, (char*)errStr);
     ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:224: recipe for target 'xmlparser.o' failed
make: *** [xmlparser.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/bundler20151111-18724-f3sw3fxmlparser-0.7.2.1/gems/xmlparser-0.7.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /tmp/bundler20151111-18724-f3sw3fxmlparser-0.7.2.1/extensions/x86-linux/2.1.0/xmlparser-0.7.2.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: please provide us the log, instead of screen shot

Comment: `xmlparser` gem was not updated since 2012. Please consider to switch to [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/), that is a standard de facto in XML parsing in ruby nowadays.

Comment: it's a dependency for other package. I need xmlparser. works in other pcs in my office

Comment: Well, I have just checked on my Ubuntu: it was installed successfully. So I would suggest you to: `apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev` and then retry with `xmlparser`.

Comment: i'm still getting the same error. Must be some conflict i don't know

Comment: OK, finally I found the reason. `gcc` inherits build flags from those, ruby was build with. In your case, it is `-Werror=format-security`, that means “treat this as an error, rather than a warning.” I believe `CFLAGS=-Wno-format-security gem install xmlparser` should finally succeed.

Comment: I've posted solution on another topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41181026/2402536